# exec-maven-plugin cannot execute .sh script: permission denied

Tags: bash, maven, exec-maven-plugin

I have a bash script which I want maven to run after the compilation phase, since the script is supposed to deploy bundles. Here is the plugin I am trying to utilize in my release module:

```
<plugin>
          <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>deploy-bundles</id>
              <phase>install</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <executable>${basedir}/deploy.sh</executable>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I have the `deploy.sh` in the correct path, so that's verified. Now when I do `mvn install` I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (deploy-bundles) on project module.release: Command execution failed. Cannot run program "/bla/bla/module.release/deploy.sh" (in directory "/bla/bla/module.release"): error=13, Permission denied -> [Help 1]
```

First, I thought it was about the bash script I wrote. So I changed it to a simple bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash          
STR="Hello World!"
echo $STR
```

however, I got the same error. So it is not about the code. Should I given maven special rights? Should use the `sudo` command?

Comment: The script must have the permission to be executed. exec-maven-plugin is not releated to that...You need to set execution attribute on linux `chmod +x deploy.sh` also you need to add that to your version control (git, subversion)...

Comment: I want everything to be done with simple `mvn install` command, since the user should be dealing with `chmod` or such. Is there a way to tell maven to handle this?

Comment: As i said you need to set the permission correctly and put that correctly into your version control...I don't know what you mean by `user should be..`?

Comment: Sorry I read your message wrong, now I got it and it did work, thanks. If you write this as answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the appropriate permissions to the script and put the permission also into your version control either git (.gitattributes) or in Subversion (svn:executable property).

Comment: Thanks. Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10783833/6533075) the correct way to do it for Git?

Comment: This [link](http://blog.lesc.se/2011/11/how-to-change-file-premissions-in-git.html) helped me to change the linux permissions :
`> git update-index --chmod=+x script.sh`

Answer (score 5):

Getting file permissions stored in VCS might be tricky, not every VCS is good at that.

Instead you could execute `/bin/bash` with your script as an argument (and remove the `#!...` line from your script).

Your configuration could look like this:

```
<configuration>
    <executable>/bin/bash</executable>
    <arguments><argument>${basedir}/deploy.sh</argument></arguments>
</configuration>
```

(And, in general case, `/bin/sh` is more portable, `bash` could be in many different places.)

Comment: Worked for me! Had to change from /bin/bash to bash simply, but it worked. Thank you!